# Android: highlighted navigation buttons at the bottom of the screens, Split Actionbar?

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

Many apps (Instagram for example) have these navigation buttons at the bottom of the screens for switching activities. A button is highlighted AFTER clicking and stays highlighted during the activity until the user switches to other activities.

I'm trying to implement these buttons in my app. Are these buttons part of the split action bar, or tabs placed at the bottom, or just regular image buttons in a group (like push-buttons/radio-buttons)? I tried using split action bar. It works well, however, I cannot figure out how to highlight or change the background of the button which was clicked. I searched but couldn't find a solution. There are postings about changing the background color of the action bar item using custom selector, but it only applies to the time the button is pressed. Since so many apps these days have these buttons, I believe there are must be solutions that I'm not aware. Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the [tabwidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) for highlighting the tab(or)button for switching in bottom

Comment: Well, the problem of using tabs is that the tab buttons will be covered by any activity that is not part of the TabHost. I do want to let user see the navigation buttons all the time.